# Android Java project - Layout not displaying correctly (Button under listview)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

**UPDATE:** Thanks everyone for your help, layout_weight is what I was after.

I am currently working on my first android project in java. I am trying to use a linearlayout which has a listview spanning most of the page but has a load more button at the bottom of the app.

This is what it SHOULD look like and is what is previewed to me in Eclipse
[image: Previewed in Eclipse]

and this is what is happening when I actually run the application

[image: When running the application]

The button for some reason is moved a lot higher then I would like, I would like it to stick to the bottom of the page and have the listview take up the rest of the screen...

Here is my layout xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="434dp"
        android:maxHeight="434dp"
        android:minHeight="434dp"
        android:background="#000000" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:maxHeight="27dp"
        android:text="Load More..."
        android:textSize="@dimen/dp12" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So my question is,

What have I done wrong or not done at all which is required to keep the button at the bottom of the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1.00"
    android:background="#000000" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:maxHeight="27dp"
    android:text="Load More..."
    android:textSize="@dimen/dp12" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting up the layout using dp measurements. Try using the weight attribute instead. It should do what you want and scale nicely.

http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/

[What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

Good Luck!